# Cannot manualy save image on disk (Nginx, Django)

Tags: python, django, unix, nginx, python-imaging-library

I have a problem with custom uploading view from form. The problem starts when i am trying to **save** to `/pathto/static/media/temp/`. Django settings `MEDIA_ROOT=/pathto/static/media`, `STATIC_ROOT=/pathto/static`. Here's the code:

```
def upload_picture(request):
    temp_file = request.FILES['picture'].read()
    image_file = BytesIO(temp_file)
    im = Image.open(image_file)
    im.save('/pathto/static/media/temp/image.jpg')
    ...
```

Permissions for `/pathto/static/media/temp/` directory

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 ... temp
```

Nginx config

```
server  {
    location /media/  {
        alias /pathto/static/media/;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /pathto/static/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

Definitely everything is ok, if `DEBUG=True` because Django starts to serve files. So probably the problems with Nginx config.
How can i fix the problem with manualy saving the image?

Comment: You hard-coded the image path that every upload goes to the exactly same file? In that case two uploads at the same time can't work.

Comment: @KlausD. That's not a problem, i just simplified the code for not paying attention on unnecessary details.

Comment: Are the files stored and just not served by nginx? Does the request return a 200?

Comment: all directory components in the /pathto/static/... must have write permissions for the username that will save the file (or one of it groups), not just the bottom level. Good luck.

Comment: @KlausD. surprisingly the problem was with Pillow library. it was my mistake for blaming Nginx. Thanks!

Comment: @shellter the permissions seemed to be the trouble, but it's ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your problem right the issue in

```
im.save('/pathto/static/media/temp/image.jpg')
```

Solution is:

On Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```

And then

```
pip install -I pillow
```

It should help